# Setting up NVIDIA VisionWorks in Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: cuda, computer-vision, gpgpu, nvidia

I seem to be having difficulties setting up VisionWorks so that I can use it from VS2013. Here is what I've done so far:

- Added C:\Program Files\NVIDIA VisionWorks\include to C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories
- Added C:\Program Files\NVIDIA VisionWorks\share\visionworks\sources\nvxio\include to C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories
- Added C:\Program Files\NVIDIA VisionWorks\lib to Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
- Added visionworks.lib to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
- Copied visionworks.dll to the Project Directory

Here's the error I'm having:

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl nvxio::checkIfContextIsValid(struct _vx_context *)" (?checkIfContextIsValid@nvxio@@YAXPEAU_vx_context@@@Z)  C:\Users\renzb\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\depthstream\dstream\dseval\main.obj    dseval

The error seems to indicate that an external link concerning nvxio is missing. However, there are no corresponding .lib or .dll files for nvxio, only include files and src files. Am I supposed to do something with the src files?

I am able to build C:\Program Files\NVIDIA VisionWorks\share\visionworks\sources using nmake using the instructions from user_guide_windows.md. Still, I can't find nvxio .dll or .lib from the resulting bin folder.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the sources, you should copy them beside your own sources and include them in your project. The linker says it can't find the implementation for this specific function, which means it is not implemented in your project nor in the libraries you use.

You could also try to build a library project with this source files in, and then link this library to your current project.

Are you familiar with libraries and the linker behaviour in general ?
Your question is not really related to any of your tags, it seems to be more related to the linker and how to build a project using external static and/or dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 2):

NVXIO is distributed in source code only as a part of samples. You need to build samples to get NVXIO binaries (see VisionWorks documentation for information about samples compilation on Windows). Alternatively, you can include NVXIO sources into your project, as Taro suggested.